# flash interactive media server 4.5 camera not grabbed

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-media-server

In preview the camera works well, but if I try to publish and see in browser there is an empty screen, please help

Comment: Some code would be helpful. We can't diagnose anything without code and/or more project details.